# How to get GTK4 in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: software-installation, application-development, gtk

GTK4 was released quite recently, and the [demo codes](https://www.gtk.org/#list-py) don't run in Ubuntu 20.04 because GTK4 is not available on the system.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gtkapp.py", line 3, in <module>
    gi.require_version('Gtk', '4.0')
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 132, in require_version
    raise ValueError('Namespace %s not available for version %s' %
ValueError: Namespace Gtk not available for version 4.0
```

While future versions of Ubuntu will have dependencies of GTK4, can we somehow develop software with GTK4 in the current LTS, 20.04?

Is the backend available as a snap/flatpak?

Comment: `libgtk-4-0` is [currently](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=libgtk-4-0&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) in Debian experimental and IIRC, Ubuntu's release when in beta/pre-release stage, fetches packages from Debian sid (unstable). So, I believe Ubuntu won't have GTK4 until `libgtk-4-0` doesn't make its way to sid.

Comment: The question received a close vote for being opinion based. Who would "how to do something" be opinion based? If it cannot be done right now, let's wait for someone to make a PPA or something.

Comment: Making PPA doesn't make sense (I think), unless you want to break the system currently running GTK3. For example, `libjson-glib-1.0-0` is a dependency of many packages but as of now, libgtk-4-0 requires a higher version of the said package which would break GTK3's dependencies. (***PS**: I didn't vote to close the question.*)

Comment: @Kulfy: But you could just install it to /opt?

Comment: @Jo-ErlendSchinstad Yes, but I'm not sure if it would create issues with GTK3. May be worth trying :)

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi Until the GTK4 story gets done, [you can install GTK4 from here](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLN_MPJUQgPVpB338zXmv084bFTH_tKDAk)  and work with that.

Comment: Is there any update here?  It's a month after 21.04 is out and Gtk is at 4.2 now and i want to try it. Do i really have to wait until end of october

Comment: @Lothar `libgtk-4` is [present](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=libgtk-4&searchon=names) in 21.04. If you really want to try GTK 4.2 right now you would have to use a rolling release distro.

Comment: I'm new to linux distribution system. Will Ubuntu usually make backports available to 20.4 LTS?